# Retrieving the URL of a clicked link in a C# WebBrowser control

Tags: c#

Okay. So, I'm making my own internet browser and I have tabs. But, I'm trying to make it a real time url updater while if you click on any link it will show up in the textbox of the url.
It will not work.
Here is the tab button.

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser Browser = new WebBrowser();
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page");
        tabControl1.SelectTab(tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1);
        Browser.Name = "Web Browser";
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser);
        ((WebBrowser)(tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0])).GoHome();
```

And here is where my textbox isn't getting the right url.

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        textBox1.Enabled = true;
        //textBox1.Text = Browser.Url.ToString();
        ((WebBrowser) (this.tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0])).Url.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you need to get all link elements of the web page you've just loaded and assign a custom function to the `HtmlElement.Click` event of that element.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = true;
    textBox1.Enabled = true;
    var linkElements = Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach(HtmlElement link in linkElements)
    {
        link.Click += (s, args) =>
        {
            // a link is being clicked
            // get the url the link is pointing to using the href attribute of the element
            textBox1.Text = link.GetAttribute("href");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Object isn't containing a definition for GetAttribute, and Click. Also, the local variable 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because it would become a different meaning.

Comment: Thank you. You just missed an extra semicolon. It's the first "}" after textBox1.Text = link.GetAttribute("href"); So it should look like.
` textBox1.Text = link.GetAttribute("href");
        };`
Also, it doesn't seem to work.
The way I have it setup is it doesn't have a webBrowser1 so, it can't run this line of code. When I press new tab it makes the webBrowser. How can I fix that?

Comment: `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` is just a callback name and is independant from the name of the `Browser` object itself. You just need to put this code in your actual `DocumentCompleted` event callback. You should take a look at some examples on the web and come back once you setup everything correctly. Oh and please mark this answer as accepted if the code provided works.